# Автоматический перезапуск консольной команды Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, сокет, сокеты

На одном из проектов на Yii2 использую сокеты. Сервер сокетов запускается командой

```
php yii socket/start-socket
```

Я его запускаю, добавив & в конце, что бы он работал в фоне. Но проходит время, и он вырубается и я не могу понять почему.

Можно ли создать какой то скрипт, который будет проверять работу сервера и в случае падения, перезапускать его?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тебе нужно чтобы за процессом следил супервизор и в случаи падения, снова запускал процесс. Я бы порекомендовал:

1. [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) (для unix систем)
2. [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/) (подойдет также и для Windows)

Comment: спасибо, работает. но почему то когда долго висит процесс - он не работает